# Can a snowboard be considered a device?

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering if it is proper to consider a snowboard a *device*?

I am writing a blog post on a person's perspective on Devices including his Technological and Transportation devices.

I am trying to use the word device to mean anything that serves a specific function, so in the case of a snowboard being a device it's function is a means of transportation.

If it is not considered a device, is there a term that better combines all of these objects that I am trying to write about including as a Phone, a Camera or Snowboard?

Comment: Yes: http://www.vail.com/faqdetail/Mountain-Information/What-sliding-devices-are-allowed.axd.  Other ski resorts have similar pages.

Comment: ......Equipment

Answer (score 1):

[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/device) defines **device**:

> n. 1. A contrivance or invention serving a particular purpose,
>   especially a machine used to perform one or more relatively simple
>   tasks.

(A definition like this should really be given in the *question*.)

The qualification in the definition makes this a less simple question. The first part of the definition certainly licenses the use of 'device' for a snowboard, whereas the caveat shows that the term is more usually reserved for *machines* (at least strongly connoting moving parts).

Using 'device' for a snowboard is not unacceptable, but, I'd say, unusual and thus less than ideal. But there might not be an ideal alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Snowboard is a device.

The definition of a device is something made or adapted for a particular purpose.

Technically a snowboard is a device since it is something made for a particular purpose.Although the term device is associate with the something that is an electronic.

Comment: Please provide the source for your definition - or did you make it up?